# Use of Having multiple contracts for different consumers

Tags: wcf, web-services

I got one interview question in **WCF**

> **What is the use of Having multiple contracts for different consumers for a web sevice?**

Could any one know the answer for the above questions? Reg WCF question, i explained about DataContract, Service Contract, Message Contract.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what they mean by different contracts.

If they mean different interfaces, then it could be a security benefit, restricting what you expose to each client.

If it is different endpoint configurations, you could use an efficient binary protocol for clients on the local net, and a compatible basic http binding for external clients. You could also have different authentication methods for each endpoint.

Comment: Not just a security issue. Multiple contracts permits the service to expose different subsets of itself to different clients for any reason. For instance you can expose one contract aimed at mobile clients that returns "small pages" of data and another for desktop clients to return all the data for a large page with a large grid.